# RandomStringGenerator to generate alphanumeric strings

Tags: java

Can I use Apache's *common-text* [`RandomStringGenerator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.html) to generate random alphanumeric strings (numbers and lowercase/uppercase letters)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, using the following code:

```
import static org.apache.commons.text.CharacterPredicates.DIGITS;
import static org.apache.commons.text.CharacterPredicates.LETTERS;

// ...

RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
        .withinRange('0', 'z')
        .filteredBy(LETTERS, DIGITS)
        .build();
```

Comment: Where are the `LETTERS` and `DIGITS` come from? Are they constants?

Comment: `import static org.apache.commons.text.CharacterPredicates.DIGITS;
import static org.apache.commons.text.CharacterPredicates.LETTERS;`. I updated the answer.

Comment: Why not cut the middle man and use `.filteredBy(Character::isLetter, Character::isDigit)`?

Comment: I think `Character::isLetter` would allow also for characters different from `a-zA-Z`, see "For example, Character.isLetter(0x2F81A) returns true because the code point value represents a letter (a CJK ideograph)" [] from [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Comment: @toKrause I misunderstood your comment. Yes, that would be option. For reference [CharacterPredicates.java](https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/text/CharacterPredicates.java)

Comment: you can even shorten it with `.filteredBy(Character::isLetterOrDigit)`

Answer (score 5):

I use this:

```
static char[] chars = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'z', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', 'a', 's',
        'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'y', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Z', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', 'A',
        'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'Y', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M' };

private static String randomString(int length) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        stringBuilder.append(chars[new Random().nextInt(chars.length)]);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

or

```
private static String randomString(int length) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        switch (new Random().nextInt(3)) {
            case 0:
                stringBuilder.append((char) (new Random().nextInt(9) + 48));
                break;
            case 1:
                stringBuilder.append((char) (new Random().nextInt(25) + 65));
                break;
            case 2:
                stringBuilder.append((char) (new Random().nextInt(25) + 97));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: This includes also the following characters though: :;<=>?@[\]^_`

Answer (score 3):

```
RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
    .selectFrom("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789".toCharArray())
    .build();
```

I kind of prefer this way rather than generating character codes and filtering out ones I don't want. And implicitly assuming that '0'..'z' includes all the codes I want, including capital letters (based on the ascii code chart).

In addition, depending on the application (eg password generation), you might want to use a CSPRNG (secure PRNG) seeded by a true-randomness source:

```
.usingRandom(new SecureRandom()::nextInt)
```

The default SecureRandom seed is from a true-randomness source of OS hardware device entropy.

Comment: To view SecureRandom PRNG seedFile/nextFile sources (for your local java compiler): `echo "import java.security.*; class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { new SecureRandom(); } }" >Test.java && javac Test.java && java -Djava.security.debug=provider Test`

Answer (score 2):

The [withinRange()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.Builder.html#withinRange(char%5B%5D...)) method accepts min/max character pairs directly. So you can do:

```
char[][] allowedCharacterRanges = {{'a','z'},{'A','Z'},{'0','9'}};

RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
    .withinRange( allowedCharacterRanges )
    .build();
```

Answer (score -1):

With Java 8 lambda expressions:

```
    private final RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder()
            .usingRandom(max -> RandomUtils.getRandomAlphanumericChar()).build();

....................

public class RandomUtils {

    private final static char[] ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O',
            'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
            'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',
            '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};

    private final static Random random = new SecureRandom();

    public static char getRandomAlphanumericChar() {
        return ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS[random.nextInt(ALPHA_NUMERIC_CHARS.length)];
    }
}
```